# Why does this Next.js code keep making requests to the specified endpoint despite conditional configuration?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

Why does this specific Next.js code continue to make calls to the indicated endpoint, even though it seems configured to conditionally request based on certain conditions? There might be an error in the conditional logic or the conditions themselves, or there could be an issue with caching or state management causing the conditions never to be properly satisfied. It's important to carefully examine the code logic, verify if the conditions are correct, and if state data is handled as intended. Additionally, debugging might be useful to better understand the program flow and pinpoint any runtime errors.

**Home.jsx**

```
import { getCategories } from "@/services/categories";

export default function Home() {
  const [categories, setCategories] = useState([]);
  const [subcategories, setSubCategories] = useState([]);
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [load, setLoad] = useState(false);
  const searchParams = useSearchParams();

  const loadValue = () => {
    
    if (categories.length == undefined) {
      if (categories.length <= 0) {
        getCategories() //loop call
          .then((data) => setCategories(data))
          .catch((err) => console.error(err));
      }
    }
    if (subcategories.length == undefined) {
      if (subcategories.length <= 0) {
        getsubcategories()
          .then((data) => setSubCategories(data))
          .catch((err) => console.error(err));
      }
    }
  };
```

**categories.js**

```
import axios from "axios";
import { url } from "./url.js";

export async function getCategories() {
  return axios
    .get(url + "/v1/categories")
    .then((res) => {
      return res.data;
    })
    .catch((err) => console.error(err));
}
```

Comment: It would be good to show and the code where you are calling the function loadValue.

Comment: is not call anywhere this is problem

Comment: So `getCategories` must be called somewhere else than

Comment: but why?...... ....